# Using Fragment layour ..... findbyViewId always NULL

Tags: android, layout, fragment, findviewbyid

I am pretty newbie with android development and I am trying to make work an easy example.

When the layout contains fragments, this fragments are inflated and the method findByViewId returns a NULL pointer. I would like to konw how to avoid that.

```
activity_main.xml 

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.todoit.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

so far the only solution I found was to dont use fragment layout :/

```
fragment_main.xml 
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.todoit.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myEditText"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

this code returned a NULL pointer

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); ListView myListView=
>   (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

the only way I found was to use this one instead.

> setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main); ListView myListView=
>   (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

all this code in the onCreate method.

could someone tell me how to solve this issue? is there a way to inflate the whole layout including fragments?

thanks a lot.
Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inflate the fragment's view in the fragment code only, not in the activity code. You use `onCreateView` method to do this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ListView myListView= (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    return v;
}
```

If you want to find your `ListView` after `onCreateView` has already been called, you can use `getView()` method:

```
ListView myListView= (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.myListView);
```

Comment: worked, thanks a lot. but some other code I need to use now after I get the Id doesnt work inside that method. 

  aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,todoItems);

it says it cannot find the constructor... before in the activity onCreate was found without issue. :?

Comment: Change `this` to `getActivity()`. `Fragment` doesn't inherit from `Context`.

Comment: the code that before in the onCreate method inside the activity worked, inside the onCreateView method just dont do anything at all. Basically I try:
ListView myListView= (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
final EditText myEditText =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
....
myListView.setAdapter(aa);
myEditText.setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener()
            {
                public boolean onKey(.....)}
            );
            return rootView;
        }

Comment: basically I just want to get the ID of the list and the edit text and capture the key stroke to add a new item to the listview.
It is a very simple example of a ToDoList app... but with fragments I cannot make it work.

Comment: @user1564193 I think it will be better if you post a new question with an updated answer. Stack Overflow should have a question on one topic and relevent answers.

Comment: ok, thanks. you are right, the original question was answered. ;)

Answer (score 0):

ListView myListView= (ListView) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.myListView); needs to be called from inside the fragment class code and not the main activity. Call it inside method onActivityCreated, by that time the onCreateView function of fragment would have succeeded

Comment: This won't work as there's no `findViewById()` method on `Fragment` class.

Comment: That's correct but your answer doesn't mention `getView()`. Please add it, I'll remove the downvote.